# Strange behaviour in customView with onClick event

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-recyclerview

I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/Fshamri/405a54bf51ebe641c579) class to draw TriangleShapeView over ImageView that changes its color and drawable image upon user click event.

in RecyclerView onBindViewHolder method, i check against 
`feedModel.isSubscribed()` then set TriangleShapeView color and drawable image accordingly:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final FeedModel feedModel =this.feedCollection.get(position);
        if (feedModel.isSubscribed()) {
            holder.mTrView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            holder.mTrView.setDrawable(holder.mTrView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check));
        } else {
            holder.mTrView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.mTrView.setDrawable(holder.mTrView.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_plus));
        }
```

in setOnClickListener:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (FeedAdapter.this.onItemClieckListener != null){
                FeedAdapter.this.onItemClieckListener.onFeedItemClicked(feedModel);
                if (feedModel.isSubscribed()) {
                    feedModel.setIsSubscribed(false);
                     notifyItemChanged(position);
                } else {
                    feedModel.setIsSubscribed(true);
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }

            }
        });
```

this works fine when items get loaded for first time but when user clickes:

**- 1st & 2nd time: drawable image got changes as desired but the color
   remains same.

 - 3rd time both drawable image and color gets changes**

i am using the following xml layout to inflate this custom view:

```
<cardView
  <RelativeLayout
  ....
 <com.xxx.TriangleShapeView
            android:id="@+id/trView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="15dp"
          TriangleShapeView:imgPadding="5dp"  
          TriangleShapeView:triangleBackground="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            TriangleShapeView:img="@drawable/ic_plus"/>
```

i believe, the FeedModel gets updated once OnClick is called and checks are fine in onBindViewHoldr method. so i think the problem is in the class mentioned in the above link

**What i am looking to achieve is**:
 if feedModel.isSubscribed then change the color to red and drawable to check-sign icon. else, keep the initial values as in the layout xml.

also react upon onClick and change the color and image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right and the error in this method.

```
 public void setBackgroundColor(int backgroundColor) {
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    invalidate();
}
```

the paint color get assigned in the constructor and onDraw method.

try to add to this method before `invalidate()` the line with `paint.setColor(backgroundColor);`

Comment: You right. i have removed paint color  from the constructor then followed your suggestion ... it works now.